# How to make data access related features work on my Visual Studio 2010 installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, sql-server-2008-r2

(I'm sorry if this ought to be asked somewhere else)

I get the following error message each time I want to access some data-related feature from my VS installation:

[image]

That is either rewire my ORM of choice, or test a database connection visually through the *Server Explorer*, etc.

What exactly should I reinstall here?

I do have *Compact Framework* installed, just in case here is a list of the related programs and features installed on this environment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the "Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tool for SQL Server Compact 4.0" and same for 3.5 (assume they are already installed) - see http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html

Comment: I downloaded Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4.0 setup and it was already installed, repair didn't help